# Nonce cookies keep on increasing and gives error Bad Request - Request Too Long

Tags: azure, openid-connect, nonce

We use OpenId Connect for the authentication purpose. We are using OWIN and the related NuGet packages that are 3.1.0. We have seen a wired issue in which OpenIdConnect cookies keep on increasing that ultimately results in "Request Too long" error as shown in the screenshot below. Any idea?

[image]

[image]